# T-SQL query to show only differences between rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that outputs the following dataset:

[image]

I need to find a way to find instance where the `unitid` column and the `stat` column do not match. An example would be if `unitid = 2, CleanCode = 10` and `stat = Started` and the next row below was `unitid = 2, CleanCode = 2` and `stat = Not Started`.

How can I create a query to find those differences?

Thanks

Comment: You need to have deterministic ordering for the "next row below it" requirement. Would that be ordered by `unitId` and `id`? Also, add the version-specific SQL tag to your question since the solution may vary by version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is a self join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.unitId
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t1.unitId = t2.unitId AND
       t1.id <> t2.id AND
       t1.cleanCode <> t2.cleanCode AND
       t1.stat <> t2.stat;
```

### Demo

I added one extra record to your sample data, because none of the data you actually showed us would end up in your expected result set.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a column that specifies the ordering, use `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(stat) over (partition by unitcode order by <ordering column>) as prev_stat
      from t
     ) t
where prev_stat <> stat;
```